# Print a variable which is inside two loops

Tags: perl

I couldn't figure it out how to escape this.

I would like to print the variable `$rfam_column`, which is inside two loops. But I cannot just write the `print` command right after the place where `$rfam_column` appears, because I would like to print other things which will be outside the loop and combine them to the printed content.

I would appreciate any advice as to what I'm doing wrong here.

```perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $in;
GetOptions('input' => \$in) or die;

if ( $in ) {

    my $input = $ARGV[0] or die;

    open (my $fh, '<', $input) or die "Can't open $input $!\n";
    chomp (my @db_file = <$fh>);
    close $fh;

    my @list = grep /RNA/, @db_file;

    my $column;
    my @column = ();

    foreach  $column ( @list ) {

        my @all_columns = split (/\t/, $column);
        my $rfam_column = $all_columns[0];

        # insert "|" between RFs

        foreach $_ ( $rfam_column ) {
            s/^/|/;
        }
    }
}

print "$rfam_column";
```

> ```
> Global symbol "$rfam_column" requires explicit package name at script_vbeta.pl line 90.
> Execution of script_vbeta.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
> ```

EDITED to include all the code and information of the input--output as suggested:

Input file is a table with n lines vs n columns like this (I extracted a few columns otherwise it would be much long to represent in a line):

```
RF00001 1302    5S ribosomal RNA
RF00006 1307    Vault RNA
RF00007 1308    U12 minor spliceosomal RNA
RF00008 1309    Hammerhead ribozyme (type III)
```

Output should be like this:

```
|RF00001|RF00006|RF00007
```

And the code (usage: script.pl -i input_file):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;
Getopt::Long::Configure("pass_through");


my $in;
GetOptions('input' => \$in) or die;

if ( $in ) {

    my $input = $ARGV[0] or die;

    open (my $fh, '<', $input) or die "Can't open $input $!\n";
    chomp (my @db_file = <$fh>);
    close $fh;

    my @list = grep /RNA/, @db_file;

    my $column;
    my @column = ();

    foreach  $column ( @list ) {

        my @all_columns = split (/\t/, $column);
        my $rfam_column = $all_columns[0];
        # insert "|" between RFs
        foreach $_ ( $rfam_column ) {
            s/^/|/;
        }
    }
}
print "$rfam_column";
```

Comment: show sample input file (with multiple RNA lines) and what output you are wanting

Comment: Please show your real program. What you have shown dies with `Undefined subroutine &main::GetOptions`

Comment: It would help you a lot if you laid your program out to be more readable. ysth and I have done it for you here so that we could read it ourselves

Comment: You have misnamed the `$column` variable, which is set to each *line* from the input file in turn. `@all_columns` contains the data in that line split into columns, and `$all_columns[0]` is the first column of the current line. Both will change for each iteration of the outer `for` loop. I don't know whether that corresponds to a misunderstanding of Perl.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm new to Perl and programming...  I edited the  post so now all the code is available.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
if ($in) {
    ...

    my @rfams;
    for my $row (@list) {
        my @fields = split(/\t/, $row);
        my $rfam = $fields[0];
        push @rfams, $rfam;
    }

    my $rfams = join('|', @rfams);
    print("$rfams\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to print other things which will be outside the loop and combine them to the $rfam_column content

You can include anything that is in an *outer scope* in `print`. You can just put your `print` statement inside the inner loop

By the way, I don't know what you mean by

```
# insert "|" between RFs

foreach $_ ($rfam_column) {
    s/^/|/;
}
```

That is the same as

```
$rfam_column =~ s/^/|/;
```

which just adds a pipe `|` character to the beginning of the string

What is an RF?

Comment: Hi Borodin, RF is short for RF0001, for example. I changed the foreach loop for the substitution function. Thanks